# Neo4j 3.1.3 with Elasticsearch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, graphaware

I'm going to integrate my Neo4j application with Elasticsearch. I'm going to try the following Neo4j plugin from GraphAware https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch

Could you please tell does it support Neo4j 3.1.3 version? Also, what version of ES should be used there ? Does it support ES 5.3.0 for example ?

Right now I have installed Elasticsearch 5.3.0 locally. Also I have added 2 jars:

```
graphaware-neo4j-to-elasticsearch-3.1.3.45.7.jar 
graphaware-server-community-all-3.1.3.46.jar
```

to my `Neo4j CE 3.1.3\plugins\` folder.

Also, I have added the following config (as descrbed here https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch#example) lines into my database configuration(`Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf`):

```
elasticsearch.host_name=http://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.index_spec=decisions:Decision(name,description)
```

But when I'm inserting the data through Spring Data Neo4j project nothing happens.. The Elasticsearch indexes still empty.

What am I doing wrong and how to make it working ?

**UPDATED**

I made some progress on this:

This is my Neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware

com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

com.graphaware.module.ES.2=com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchModuleBootstrapper

com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty=ID()
com.graphaware.module.ES.node=hasLabel('Decision')
com.graphaware.module.ES.relationship=(false)

com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=localhost
com.graphaware.module.ES.port=9200

com.graphaware.module.ES.index=neo4j-index
```

In my application I have an entity: `Decision`. `Decision` is a complex type with a  big  parent hierarchy:

`Decision extends Commentable extends Votable extends Flaggable ... and so on.`

Right now I'm adding ~60 Decision nodes to my Neo4j database but I'm unable to see all of them at ES. I can see only the first one with a duplication per parent class in hierarchy.

This what what I have now:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/neo4j-index-node/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 8,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Decision",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Authorable",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Subscribable",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "BaseEntity",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Votable",
100  7842  100  7842    0     0   7842      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 7658kl",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Flaggable",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Likeable",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Commentable",
      "_id" : "null",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "avgVotesWeight" : 0.0,
        "updateDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:36.883Z",
        "nameSlug" : "antivirus-software-for-windows",
        "lowerName" : "antivirus software for windows",
        "description" : "This is a non-exhaustive list of notable antivirus and Internet Security software, in the form of comparison tables, according to their platform (e.g. desktop and server, mobile, etc.)",
        "totalDislikes" : 0,
        "totalChildDecisions" : 59,
        "totalCriteria" : 19,
        "multiVotesAllowed" : false,
        "totalCharacteristics" : 8,
        "totalComments" : 0,
        "totalFlags" : 0,
        "likeSum" : 0.0,
        "totalVotes" : 665,
        "name" : "Antivirus software for Windows",
        "totalLikes" : 0,
        "createDate" : "2017-04-19T09:17:20.347Z"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Why all of the Decision's sub-classes(like `Votable`, `Likeable`) are also duplicated there? As you can see from my config I have tried to exclude everything except:

`com.graphaware.module.ES.node=hasLabel('Decision')`

My goal is to index only `Decision` nodes at ES.

Also, why the only single decision from ~60 is indexed there ? I think "_id" : "null" at the Elasticsearch JSON output is related to this issue. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems our documentation has been weird about the usage of the internal id as document id :

Replace this line :
`com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty=ID()`

By this

`com.graphaware.module.ES.keyProperty=ID()`

However if you use the uuid module as well, it is best to use "uuid" instead of the internal ID

I tested on community 3.1.3 with the versions mentioned and it is working.

`{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" :{
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Decision",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"id":123,"title":"Ibiza"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "neo4j-index-node",
      "_type" : "Decision",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"id":123,"title":"Weird Decision"}
    } ]
  }
}`

If your nodes have both labels Decision and Votable, then you have to exclude them in the configuration like this :

`com.graphaware.module.ES.node=hasLabel('Decision') && !hasLabel('Votable') && !hasLabel('BaseEntity')`